# I want to start studying mathematics again,where should i start??

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, book-recommendation, foundations

So, currently I'm a CSE student and just gave 2nd years end semester exams.  So in my syllabus there is some mathematics but now I'm more interested in mathematics and want to continue learning/solving mathematics.

my past experience is I prepared for JEE-Advanced and mathematics(ig this puts me high school math equivalent in American standard) was my stronghold, in first year I studied calculus and probability and in third semester discrete mathematics. So my question is now where should I start??

and what should be my plan??

sorry for bad English....
thanks for your time

Comment: It depends on what you want to do. You're kind of at the stage where math stops looking like a strict progression of classes and starts branching off in different directions. That said, as a computer science student myself I have begun to encounter some multivariable calculus and linear algebra related to AI, so that might be a good place to look

Comment: @StephenDonovan Thanks,are there some books which you will suggest ??

Comment: I don't know if I'll be able to help with that, I learned much more through course materials and online resources than books. One resource I would suggest if you need support for calculus is Paul's Notes from Lamar University: https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/ But that's probably the best I can do

Comment: *I prepared for JEE-Advanced and mathematics(ig this puts me high school math equivalent in American standard)* --- FYI, while many of these topics are covered in American high schools (but many are also not covered), the depth of coverage needed for the JEE is significantly deeper and the problems significantly harder than anything American high school students will encounter (except perhaps to top $2\%$ or so who participate in the various AMC math contests).

Comment: I would suggest you look at *Mathematical Analysis* by Apostol and *Algebra* by Artin (but not the Pearson India edition - the PHI edition is OK).